# How to determine which file between the two is run first in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to debug laravel code, but the laravel code I am dealing with in packages, and its being extends to other classes from other packages.

Now given I open controller, the some file example datatable. How do I know which one is run first?

Comment: use `debug_backtrace()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dead debug `dd('file1')` and `dd('file2')` in your files, and you will see which `dd` is called first